# Folder in Document library not accessible

Tags: document-library, sharepoint-server

I have a really strange problem on one of my SP2010 servers. Insinde a document library, there are a few dozens of folders, which in turn contain some more folders.

One specific folder does not open on click. It sends a get Request, which never finishes. If I try to open the document library via explorer, I am getting the error "Network path not found".

The logs contain no clue on what is goind wrong. All I can see is a GET request.

I apprecieate any hints on how to solve this problem.

Comment: Try via SharePoint Designer? Can you select the row, and access the ribbon, and try manage permissions? Try something to access the folder in another way. Might be corrupted.

Comment: I have tried, access via browser, explorer & SP Designer 2010. If it is corrupted, am I able to save/delete or recreate it? Simply using the backup is just not possible in my case.

Comment: See if you can select it and delete it